# jupyter notebook widgets don't display

Tags: ipywidgets

I've been running several **Jupyter notebooks** with sliding interact widgets for years with no problems.  Suddenly all these notebooks no longer display the sliders. No errors are displayed!
The only possible change to my system has been to install JupyterLab in addition to Jupyter Notebook. I am not using JupyterLab yet for anything......Could having both programs installed cause the above malfunction?
If not, where can I look for identifying and correcting this situation.
I am using Linux Mint 21, Python 3.
Thanks for any hints.